# How to enter data in the textarea in zig zag manner (HTML)

Tags: javascript, html, css

Typically the textarea takes the input in vertical manner. If we press enter it goes to next line in vertically (see left image)

[image]

[image]

But,is there any way to split into two columns so that, if i press enter does it goes to horizontally(zig zag manner)(see right image)

Comment: There is no such thing as “columns” in a textarea to begin with. If you wanted any, you’d have to facilitate that yourself (for example by dynamically inserting the correct amount of spaces after a the content of the first “column”, in every line.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use tabs

```js
document.getElementById("ta").addEventListener("keydown",function(e) {
  if (e.code === "Enter") {
    this.value = this.value.split(/\s+/).map((word,i) => `${word}${i%2===0 ? "\t" : "\n"}`).join("")
  }    
})
```

```html
<textarea id="ta" cols="80" rows="20" wrap="hard"></textarea>
```